# Where are the Docker container files on Windows 10?

Tags: docker

I am using Docker Desktop for Windows 10. I ran a Prestashop container and then going in the CLI of the container, it redirects to the root of the Prestashop folder but the path is “/var/www/html”.

So, I know that Docker is using a virtual environment based on Linux, but I would like to know the path of my Prestashop files in the Windows file system.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The containers are stored in a hidden folder,

`C:\ProgramData\Docker`

Windows containers and images are located in a folder located in `C:\ProgramData\Docker` on the `C:\ drive`, unless you are using a different drive letter where the operating system is installed.

Comment: Thank you but even when I check the "hidden files" checkbox, I still dont see any other directory than 'cli-plugins' and 'config'

Comment: If you are using Hyper-v then go to `c:\users\public\documents\hyper-v\virtual hard disks` as the containers are stored on the VM hard drive

Comment: I don't think I use Hyper-v, I have tried the path you provided, it cannot find it

Comment: Docker desktop uses Hyper-V please look at the virtual hard disks.

Comment: after some research I found that I have this folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V BUT it's empty (also checked the 'hidden files' checkbox)

Comment: Also I have Windows Family so I don't think I can use hyper-v

Comment: You are using windows 10 home? On the system tray next to the time, locate the docker icon and open settings, and then click on advanced, and then towards the bottom, look at the images and volumes VHD textbox, and this should tell you the location.

Comment: I just edited my post, so you can see that I run Windows Family (I guess it's the same as Home) and also that there is no Advanced section in Docker settings

Comment: For your version of docker desktop In Settings, in the Resources, advanced, in the text box disk image location, the file path would be the location.

Comment: I edited with another screenshot, still no Advanced section...

Comment: You are using docker wsl2 which has differences in the GUI as well, I have read about a hidden network share for wsl2, you can use Windows explorer to access this by navigating to `\\wsl$` and the wsl volumes should appear.

Comment: Using Windows Explorer, I found my docker wsl2 WordPress installation in a randomly-named directory under \\wsl$\docker-desktop\mnt\host\wsl\docker-desktop-bind-mounts\Ubuntu-20.04\